# What does 2月头的样子 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following sentence:

> 2月头的样子，有一起去泰国的朋友吗？

It would mean something like:

> Any friend who can travel to Thailand together at the start of February?

However, what does the 样子 mean?

The dictionary says appearance, shape, pattern, etc... as the meaning, and they are what I know on the word 样子. But they don’t seem to be a good fit in this context.

So what does it mean and what is the difference with or without 的样子?

Comment: "Is there any friend who would like to travel with company to Thailand at the start of February as likely time?" bkrs：样子，(4) [tendency; likelihood] [口]∶形势; 趋势 4) 表示约略的用语。
如：「那个人我好像在哪里见过的样子。」(口) （趋势） tendency; likelihood:
天像是要下雨的样子。 It looks like rain.
看样子你今天有点不高兴。 It seems you are not quite yourself today.; You don't seem to be quite yourself today.

Comment: With `的样子`, the time is not certain yet. `的样子` means `like that` 的样子.

Comment: So it is similar (or same) to 左右? Can you make it as an answer?

Comment: or strike "as likely time" and insert "most likely" in front of "at the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

的样子 = seem like/ look like/ apparently

2月头的样子 (seems like early February) doesn't look like a complete sentence because we don't know 'what' seems like early February

If you wrote

> "2月头的样子, (我会有一个长假)" --> It seems like early February, (I will have a long vacation time)
>
> or rephrase it as
>
> "It seems like I will have a long vacation time early February"

Then it would make more sense.

If you insist on just write "2月头的样子，有一起去泰国的朋友吗？" Then a topic must had been mentioned in the context earlier.

For example:

> Q: "你什么时候去旅行？" ( When will you travel?)
>
> A: "2月头的样子" (something like early February)

Blaszard wrote:

> *So it is similar (or same) to 左右?*

Using 左右 (around) in this context would be fine, but the wording is different. As I stated in the beginning of this post, 的样子 means "seem like/ look like/ apparently"

> "2月头**左右**, 有一起去泰国的朋友吗？" (Are there any friend who would go to Thailand with me **around** early February?)

It would be a complete sentence.

Answer (score 3):

It means “about the beginning of February ” 
”二月头的样子” means “大概二月初”